# Safe multithreaded file creation in java

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, synchronized

I have a webapp that needs to sometimes download some bytes from a url and package it up and send back to the requester. The downloaded bytes are stored for a little while so they can be reused if the same url is needed to be downloaded. I am trying to figure out how best to prevent the threads from downloading the same url at the same time if the requests come in at the same time. I was thinking of creating a class like below that would prevent the same url from being downloaded at the same time. If a url is unable to be locked then it either waits until its not locked anymore to try and download it as long as it does not exist after the unlock.

```
public class URLDownloader
{
    HashMap<String,String> activeThreads = new HashMap<String,String>();

    public synchronized void lockURL(String url, String threadID) throws UnableToLockURLException
    {
        if(!activeThreads.containsKey(url))
            activeThreads.put(url, threadID)
        else
            throw UnableToLockURLException()
    }

    public synchonized void unlockURL(String url, String threadID)
    {
        //need to check to make sure its locked and by the passed in thread
        returns activeThreads.remove(url); 
    }

    public synchonized void isURLStillLocked(String url)
    {
        returns activeThreads.contains(url); 
    }

}
```

Does anyone have a better solution for this? Does my solution seem valid? Are there any open source components out there that already do this very well that I can leverage?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you don't need a lock, since if there are multiple requests to download the same URL, the point is to download it only once.

Also, I think it would make more sense in terms of encapsulation to put the check for a stored URL / routine to store new URLs in the `URLDownloader` class, rather than in the calling classes. Your threads can simply call e.g. `fetchURL()`, and let `URLDownloader` handle the specifics.

So, you can implement this in two ways. If you don't have a constant stream of download requests, the simpler way is to have only one `URLDownloader` thread running, and to make its `fetchURL` method `synchronized`, so that you only download one URL at a time. Otherwise, keep the pending download requests in a central `LinkedHashSet<String>`, which preserves order and ignores repeats.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to keep a `ConcurrentHashSet<String>` to keep track of your unique URLs visible to all your threads. This construct might not exist directly in the java library but can easily constructed by a ConcurrentHashMap like so: `Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<String,Boolean>())`